# What is the expected number of correct matches that the medium will make (by chance)?

Tags: probability

In a test of ‘psychometry’ the car keys and wrist watches of 5 people are given to a medium.
The medium then attempts to match the wrist watch with the car key of each person. What is the expected
number of correct matches that the medium will make (by chance)?

I am stuck with this problem. I know that to obtain the expected number of matches, I need to first obtain the probability of getting a match. But the probability of getting a match is different after every guess the medium takes. So for example the probability of making a match for the first guess is $1/5$ since there is $1$ watch out of the $5$ that matches the corresponding key. And then after that guess the probability of a match is $1/4$ and so on. But how do I get a general probability? Am I reasoning about this problem the wrong way?

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way.  What is the probability of exactly $5$ matches?  $\frac{1}{120}$.  What is the probability of exactly $4$ matches?  $0$.  Determine the probability of exactly $1, 2$, and $3$ matches and go from there.

Comment: Cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/546894/119261

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach is to use linearity of expectation. Say we line up all watches and then keep a key below each watch. If $X$ is the random variable representing number of matches,

$E(X) = \sum \limits_{k = 1}^5 E(Y_k)$

where $Y_k$ is $1$ if $k$th watch gets a matching key. Now what is $E(Y_1)$ for example?

$E(Y_1) = 1 \cdot P(Y_1) + 0 \cdot (1- P(Y_1)) = \frac{1}{5}$. There are $5$ keys and probability that the matching key is kept next to the first watch is $1/5$.

Adding, you get $E(X) = 1$

---

You can also use derangement. Using derangement, if there are $n$ watches and $n$ keys, for every $k$ *exact* matches out of $n$, rest $(n-k)$ watches and keys do not match. Number of ways to do that is derangement of $(n-k)$. So, if $X$ is the random variable representing the number of matches,

$E(X) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum \limits_{k=0}^n k \cdot {n \choose k} \cdot ~ !(n-k) ~$ where $!(n-k)$ is derangement of $(n-k)$ elements.

I will leave the working to you but you should get the same answer as above.